# Solving this Laplacian Equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential, laplacian

How do I solve the following?

$\frac{∂^2\phi}{∂x^2}$ + $\frac{∂^2\phi}{∂y^2}$ + $\lambda^2\phi$ = $0$

To start of with, is it right to consider using the method of separation of variables, or is there another way to start tackling this problem.

Comment: This is the [Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation#Solving_the_Helmholtz_equation_using_separation_of_variables) and can be solved using separation of variables, Laplace transform or Fourier transform, depending on your domain.

Comment: thank you, yes, Helmholtz does look familiar. good spot.